# Azure powershell Get-AzAutomationWebhook: Parameter set cannot be resolved

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

When I attempt getting a webhook by name, running this command against Azure powershell

```
Get-AzAutomationWebhook -Name "WhName" -RunbookName "RB_Name" -ResourceGroupName "rgname" -AutomationAccountName "MyAutomationAccount"
```

I get the following error.

> Get-AzAutomationWebhook: Parameter set cannot be resolved using the
> specified named parameters. One or more parameters issued cannot be
> used together or an insufficient number of parameters were provided

and it works fine, if I remove the ***-Name parameter***

```
Get-AzAutomationWebhook -RunbookName "RB_Name" - ResourceGroupName "rgname" -AutomationAccountName "MyAutomationAccount"
```

What is the problem here?  why can't it work with the ***-Name parameter*** as documentation says?

Comment: You should have a look at the documentation on [Parameter Sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parameter_sets?view=powershell-7.3). You're locked into the parameter set for which parameter you've specified.

Comment: Webhooks will already be assigned to specific runbooks. Also, we trying to access the webhook by executing code from a runbook. There is no need to provide a separate `runbookname` parameter. Simply give a `name` parameter with the webhook name, including the automation account and resource group. @Dmitriy Ryabin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I also received the same error as you when I tried in my environment.*

[image]

After a workaround on your issue, I figured it out that passing both `runbook name` and `name` parameters creating a conflict inside the runbook. Because webhooks will already be assigned to specific runbooks.

Moreover, we are already trying to access the webhook by executing code from a runbook itself, there is no need to provide a separate `runbookName` parameter. Simply give a `Name` parameter (Webhook Name) including the `automation account` and `resource group`.

*As detailed above, I tried to execute the command in below format and was able to retrieve the webhook details successfully as shown.*

```
Get-AzAutomationWebhook -Name "newwebhook" -ResourceGroupName "<Resourcegroup>" -AutomationAccountName "newauto"
```

***Output:***

[image]

*Alternatively, if you want to retrieve the webhook only by checking the runbook name, use below script.*

```
$runbooklist = (Get-AzAutomationRunbook -AutomationAccountName "newauto" -ResourceGroupName "<resourcegroup>").Name
if($runbooklist -eq "newrunbook"){
Get-AzAutomationWebhook -Name "newwebhook" -ResourceGroupName "<resourcegroup>" -AutomationAccountName "newauto"
}
```